# I can't upload react-native expo projects on github

Tags: git, react-native

I don't know what it is, I create projects in the git repository folder and I try to upload this project but it won't, it says it doesn't have a file.
And the name of this folder in git appears with the initial letter duplicated
I had developed a small project and tried to send it but I couldn't, I created other projects with nothing more than the created files and it won't.
React native projects are expo

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you tried committing changes from terminal?

Comment: Do you say change any files? If so, yes

Answer (score 0):

Try using terminal and see if it gives the same problem:

```
/* go to ReactNative-projects parent directory and open cmd from there. 
   and push the changes to your GitHub from then terminal like below: 
*/

>git add .

>git commit -m "initial commit"

>git push origin main
```

If the repo is initialized properly then it should do the job

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem.
Expo created an extra Github Repo in my own Github Repo.
Not sure if this is the best way but I deleted the ".git" folder in my Expo App. Normally, this folder is invisible so you have to activate "show hidden elements" in your explorer (Win10).

Please copy your repo first and push other changes because you can destroy your repository with this action.

Answer (score 0):

If you use expo project than
you will need to install gitbush
git status
git add .
git commit -m "enter meassage"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin
git push -u origin main